# Make logs append-only with logrotate

Tags: linux, security, logrotate

I was wondering if it's possible to use prerotate and postrotate in logrotate.conf.

The thing is I want to make logs append only, normally I'd add `chattr -a` to prerotate and `chattr +a` to postrotate in scripts in `/etc/logrotate.d`, but what if I want this to be default setting for all logs? Can it be defined in `logrotate.conf`? What about the filename? Or am I doing it completely wrong and there is another way to make all logs handled by logrotate append-only?